# send parameter from view-model to constructor of another view-model vol.2

Tags: wpf, ioc-container, mef, caliburn.micro

I try implement advance on my question form here: [send parameter from view-model to constructor of another view-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450712/send-parameter-from-view-model-to-constructor-of-another-view-model).

I have one shell-view model and 2 view-model. I need pass object from one view-model to other view model(constructor.)

My view models look like this:

**LogOnViewModel:**

```
public interface ILogOnViewModel : IScreen, IDataErrorInfo
{
    string Nick { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
    bool CanLogOn { get; set; }
    void LogOn(string nick, string password);
}


public class LogOnViewModel : Screen,ILogOnViewModel
{

    //[Import]
    //private IShellViewModel _shellViewModel;
}
```

**MessangerViewModel:**

```
 public interface  IMessengerViewModel:IScreen
    {
        BitmapImage AvatarImage { get; set; }
        string AvatarStatus { get; set; }
        KeyValuePair<string, Friend> SelectedFriend { get; set; }
    }

    public class MessengerViewModel : Screen,IMessengerViewModel
    {
    }
```

In shell-view model I try make abstract factory for view-models.

**ShellViewModel:**

```
 public interface IFactory
    {
        ILogOnViewModel CreateLogOnViewModel();
        IMessengerViewModel CreateMessengerViewModel();
    }

    public class ConcreteFactory : IFactory
    {
        #region Implementation of IFactory

        public ILogOnViewModel CreateLogOnViewModel()
        {
            return new LogOnViewModel();
        }

        public IMessengerViewModel CreateMessengerViewModel()
        {
            return new MessengerViewModel();
        }

        #endregion
    }


    public interface IShellViewModel
    {
        void ShowLogOnView();
        void ShowMessengerView();
    }

    [Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShellViewModel
    {
        private ConcreteFactory _factory;

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            _factory=new ConcreteFactory();
            ShowLogOnView();
        }

        public void ShowLogOnView()
        {
            ActivateItem(_factory.CreateLogOnViewModel());
            //ActivateItem(IoC.Get<LogOnViewModel>());
        }

        public void ShowMessengerView()
        {
            ActivateItem(_factory.CreateMessengerViewModel());
            //ActivateItem(IoC.Get<MessengerViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

My problem is : How can I call method from Shell-view-model in LogOnVieModel. I get advance that is bad use IoC and import attribute on inport shell-view-model into another view. Supposudely is better use event agrregator on this. But I dont know how use this class in my problem.

I think, publish method from shell-view-model and handle in logon-view-model.

But I think that all I do now is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your code slightly. To start, I think its best to decouple your implementation of `IFactory` (and rename it to something less generic), e.g.:

```
public interface IViewModelFactory
{
  ILogOnViewModel CreateLogOnViewModel(IShellViewModel shellViewModel);
}
```

(I've omitted some of your code). Next, make sure you `Export` your `ConcreteFactory` (and again, rename).  We force the factory method to take an instance of your `IShellViewModel` contract.

```
[Export(typeof(IViewModelFactory))]
public class DefaultViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory
{
  public ILogOnViewModel CreateLogOnViewModel(IShellViewModel shellViewModel)
  {
    return new LogOnViewModel(shellViewModel);
  }
}
```

And adjust your `LogOnViewModel` to take in that instance of `IShellViewModel` passed from the factory.

```
public class LogOnViewModel : ILogOnViewModel
{
  private readonly IShellViewModel _shellViewModel;

  public LogOnViewModel(IShellViewModel shellViewModel)
  {
    _shellViewModel = shellViewModel;
  }

  public void SomeOperation()
  {
    // Do work with _shellViewModel;
  }
}
```

Next, we'll change the `ShellViewModel` to have it be constructed and a dependency injected for the factory it will consume:

```
[Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShellViewModel
{
  private readonly IViewModelFactory _factory;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public ShellViewModel(IViewModelFactory factory)
  {
    _factory = factory;
  }

  public void ShowLogOnView()
  {
    var model = _factory.CreateLogOnViewModel(this);
    ActivateItem(model);
  }
}
```

The `ImportingConstructor` instructs MEF to use that constructor and to inject the appropriate types.

Hope that points you in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you very, much it looks good and smart. I am beginner in wpf, mvvm so sometimes I am confuse and helpless.